# Using Docker through proxy ssh error

Tags: linux, git, ssh, proxy, docker

I have several problem when i use docker on linux machine(Ubuntu 14.04). There is a proxy on my network which did not allow ssh. So i configured my machine to use ssh through http with netcat-openbsd.

I configured my host gitlab on my machine like this:

```
Host gitlab
User        name.lastname
Hostname    my_gitlab.com
IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/my_ssh_key
ProxyCommand    /bin/nc -X connect -x proxy.example.net:80 %h %p
IdentitiesOnly    yes
```

And it works perfectly when i try to get repo from my machine. 
So i configured my docker with the same configuration but I get this error

> ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

I tried to configure the http_proxy https_proxy in the /etc/default/docker
but nothing change.

And when I use Mac OS, my docker works perfectly with the same configuration.

Someone know what's happen?

Answer (score 0):

Have you copied the newly generated `my_ssh_key.pub` to the server?  I think the ssh server `gitlab`does not recognize the ssh key coming from your docker.